# Graphql Date of the event is passed, how to update automaticly is Completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, prisma

I have no idea how to phrase this question and to be honest, when I think about it, this should have a really simple answer but for some reason, I couldn't find the best way to do it.

I'm building a React Native app with a Prisma backend. I don't want to involve the front end at all to solve this. I have a session model that has a date of the event and isCompleted param. I would like to be able to update isCompleted when the date of the event is in the past automatically. Backend is running on Heroku server, without setting up a cron job or something else, is this possible to do?

here is the model and update code I have, but not sure where to tie this to make sure it always updates all the sessions based on the time.

```
export const SessionUpdate = {
updateSessionCompletion: async (parent, args, context): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      const session = await prisma.session.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: args.id,
        },
      });
      if (session && session.date < new Date()) {
        console.log(session.date, new Date());

        return await prisma.session.update({
          where: {
            id: args.id,
          },
          data: {
            isCompleted: true,
          },
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
}
```

```
model Session {
  id             String   @id @default(dbgenerated()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt      DateTime @default(now())
  // updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
  isCompleted    Boolean  @default(false)
  title          String
  date           DateTime
  isCanceled     Boolean  @default(false)

}
```

Comment: "*I would like to be able to update isCompleted*" - why? Does this trigger any other actions? Do you even need to store this value and access it from elsewhere? Instead, just dynamically resolve the `isCompleted` value by comparing the `.data` with `Date.now()` every time it is queried.

Comment: Yes, it is needed for list of the sessions to work properly. and there will be some queries that needs to be happening based on this true-false value where the date might be different.

Comment: Then you can't really avoid a cron-job infrastructure.